# How can i install firefox34.0.5?

Tags: software-installation

I am new on Ubuntu 
I downloaded the latest version of firefox,but  I don't know how do I install it

Thank you

Comment: My understanding is that FireFox 34 should be available on [Ubuntu quite soon](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/12/firefox-34-changes-include-hello-html5-webide), from the repositories.  You may be better off waiting for that.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRl + ALT + T.  then type in the the following

```
sudo apt-get upgrade firefox
```

then type `Y`

At which point Ubuntu will then upgrade Firefox with any hassles.

Comment: this wont update your firefox to version 34. Canonical have not release that version yet. from them 33 is the latest version

Comment: i tried this method, my firefox is stuck at 33

Answer (score 0):

If you already download the firefox, you can follow this step, it is from mozilla it self:

1. Download Firefox from the Firefox download page to your home
   directory.
2. Open a Terminal and go to your home directory: cd ~
3. Extract the contents of the downloaded file: tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2
4. Close Firefox if it's open.
5. To start Firefox, run the firefox script in the firefox folder: ~/firefox/firefox

You can find more in here
[Guide To Install Firefox on Linux from Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux)

Comment: This applies two different versions to Firefox.  You need to remove the 33 from ubuntu Terminal